# How to use the front camera with react-native-document-scanner?

Tags: react-native

Working on a react-native app, I'm using [react-native-document-scanner](https://github.com/Michaelvilleneuve/react-native-document-scanner) because I need to detect documents. However I need to switch between the front and the back camera. Is there a way to simply implement that or is there a package allowing it ? (react-native-camera does not suits my needs)

Answer (score 0):

The creator of this package nicely implemented this feature especially for the need of this project. Many thanks to him !

Now the boolean props "useFrontCam" is available.